# Same adding action but different results in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create new node with unique Id in Javascript. For this I created a button

```
<input type="button" value="Add Field" onclick="AddField(this.parentElement);" />
```

And Javascript function

```
AddField = function (ParentDom){
     var uniqueValue = ParentDom.children.length;
     var newNode = "<input id='InputName"+uniqueName+"' type='text' dir='ltr' autocomplete='on' class='form-field marge-top-20' placeholder='Name Eng' value='' oninput='SafeCopy(this, document.getElementById('inputName"+uniqueName+"')); return false;'>";
     //here will be a code to add `newNode` as last child to `ParentDom`
}
```

but when I debug the code I get that

```
newNode = <input id="InputName7" type="text" dir="ltr" autocomplete="on" class="form-field marge-top-20" placeholder="Name Eng" value="" oninput="SafeCopy(this, document.getElementById(" inputname7'));="" return="" false;'="">
```

I can't understand why

`id="InputName7"`

works, but

`document.getElementById(" inputname7'));="" return="" false;'=""`

gets messed up.

After many answers that suggested to add backslash to single quotes I stiil get messed up result:

Code:

```
<input id=\'InputName" + uniqueName + "\' type='text' dir='ltr' autocomplete='on' class='form-field marge-top-20' placeholder='Name Eng' value='' oninput='SafeCopy(this, document.getElementById(\'inputName" + uniqueName + "\')); return false;'>
```

Result:

```
"<input id="InputName7" type="text" dir="ltr" autocomplete="on" class="form-field marge-top-20" placeholder="Name Eng" value="" oninput="SafeCopy(this, document.getElementById(" inputname7'));="" return="" false;'="">"
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly got it working! At the end there is no need to add backslashes! What needed to be done is to remove **ALL** single quotes inside single quotes and the code works:

```
var newNode = "<input id='InputName"+uniqueName+"' type='text' dir='ltr' autocomplete='on' class='form-field marge-top-20' placeholder='Name Eng' value='' oninput=SafeCopy(this, document.getElementById('inputName"+uniqueName+"'))>";
```

And it works!

The problem was this code:

```
'SafeCopy(this, document.getElementById('inputName"+uniqueName+"')); return false;'
```

as you can see I have a single quotes inside single quotes .  After I changed it to:

```
SafeCopy(this, document.getElementById('inputName"+uniqueName+"'))
```

It worked like it should!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put backslashes before your singlequotes, or your code will be messed up inside your `oninput`.

```
oninput='SafeCopy(this, document.getElementById(\'inputName"+uniqueName+"\')); return false;'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner quotes are not escaped. You should add backslashes before the single quotes in this part:

```
document.getElementById('inputName"+uniqueName+"')
```

because they occur in a part that is already quoted by single quotes. So:

```
document.getElementById(\'inputName"+uniqueName+"\')
```

(Before the correction to your question you had `<div class='block'>`, which is ignored, because you don't close the tag.)

Also check the capitalisation of `inputName`. It probably should be `InputName`. But then still it looks strange you want to call:

```
SafeCopy(this, document.getElementById(\'InputName"+uniqueName+"\')
```

... as both arguments will refer to the same element, i.e. the `input` on which the event was triggered.

Answer (score 0):

- `uniqueName` isn't defined anywhere, it should be uniqueValue.
- You're building the parameter for `getElementById` incorrectly. It should be `getElementById('InputName" + uniqueValue + "')`. Notice the parameter is case sensitive.
- Div tag isn't closed in newNode